# How to find the minimal polynomial.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $\alpha=\sqrt[8] 10$ show $\alpha$ is an algebraic number over $\mathbb{Q}$ and find it's minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Here is what I have so far:

Let $f(X)=X^8-10 \in \mathbb{Q}[X] \implies f(\alpha)=(\sqrt[8] 10)^{8}-10=10-10=0$ so $\alpha$ is a root of $f(X)$ and $\alpha$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Now how would I got about showing it is the minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$? I believe it is but I'm not entirely sure how to go about proving it is.

Also could anyone give me an idea of how to prove it and find the function $f(X)$ for a different number so I can get a feel of what is needed in differing examples?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to prove that $f(X)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}.$ Note that $2$ is a prime number who divides $10$, doesn't divide $1$ and $2^2$ doesn't divide $10.$ Hence the conclusion by Eisenstein criterion.